# Excel duplicate line and apply formula

Tags: excel

I need some help with the following please.

[image: excel1]

I need excel to duplicate the same line 4 additional times and update "Selling Price" according to the next markup Column.  In the picture above "Selling Price" is using "Class Retail Markup %".
Formula:  =((N2/100)*L2)+L2

The below is what I'm trying to achieve, but I need it to be automated as this is one item of thousands.
[image]

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

will be a lot of work if not done with VBA. but you could do it like that:

Insert the 5 lines manually but have everything as a reference. A3 to A6 will all have `=A2` (same for column B to J and L) (for K directly type the 2 to 5)
then in `M3` type `=(O2/100+1)*L3` and for `M4` `=(P2/100+1)*L4`. `M5` is `=(Q2/100+1)*L5` and `M6` becomes `=(R2/100+1)*L6`.

Now copy the whole rows 3 to 5.

at the next dataset select the line below it and right-click it -> "insert copied cells" (repeat the copy/paste step for every entry)

to do the copy-paste part via macro:

```
Sub Macro1()
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 47861 To 8 Step -1
    Rows("3:6").Copy
    Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown
  Next
End Sub
```

Make sure to use the correct ranges or at least split it up to do it for a short part to test it... can take a long time to do all lines in one step...

Comment: thanks, but do do this for 47861 lines is not an option :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data in this sheet(aka sheet1) doesn't get used by a formula in another sheet, you might have an option to create a new sheet (aka sheet2) with exactly the same headers. (If you have formulae in other sheets reading your 47861 lines of data, then this might not be the method as you will have to relink all those into sheet2. To check, use "Trace Dependents" in sheet1)

In cell A2 of Sheet2, write this formula:

```
=HLOOKUP(A$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$R$47862,(INT(ROW(Sheet1!A2)-2)/5)+2,0)
```

Explanation: It will look up the column head e.g."Internal ID" from sheet2 in sheet1, in your table (which I presume is 47861 lines, hence "Sheet1!$A$1:$R$47862" in the formula). In row index no of hlookup, there is a play around with getting row index no to repeat 5 times.

You can copy that formula downwards in sheet2 to A239306 (since 47861*5=239305). You can copy the row across to all your columns up to R in sheet2, except K and M (assumption you are okay 5 repetitions in columns N to R).

In sheet2, cellK2:

```
=MOD((ROW()-2),5)
```

You can drag this down to K239306. That populates all columns except M.

In sheet2, from M2 to M6, you can write down 5 formulae with different calculations of your SP, and then copy 5 of them as a block and paste them all the way down as a block over 239305 cells, from M2 to M239306.